# regular expression to match word-word or word

Tags: regex

any ideas on how to match any word dash any word without spaces or any word using regular expression.

here is an example:

```
Test    status
ab      pass
a       pass
hello   pass
helo-   fail
he-hel  pass
he he   fail
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any regexp yet? Have a look at [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/), great tool to understand regexps.

Comment: what will be the status of `ha-he-hello` and `ha--hello`?

Comment: Try [`^[\w-]+$(?<!-$)`](https://regex101.com/r/pE4lQ4/1) or [`^[\w-]+\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/pE4lQ4/2). Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like so should do the trick: `^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)?$`.

This will look for one or more letters, optionally followed by a dash and more letters. The `^` and `$` anchors ensure that the match is done from the beginning, till the end of the string. Without them, something such as `foo-` will be accepted.

Comment: foo- fails in the match that I want to add!

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie: Why would you want to add `foo-` to match. You excluded that pattern in your question.